# Is this a Cauchy sequence?

Tags: cauchy-sequences

Consider a sequence of function defined on a compact interval $[-k,k]$ of $\mathbb{R}$ by
$$f_n(x) := \cos\left(\frac{x}{2n}\right)\text{sinc}\left(\frac{x}{2n}\right),$$
where $\text{sinc}(y) := \frac{\sin(y)}{y}$.

Given $\varepsilon > 0$, is it possible to find $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that
$$ m, n \geq N ~~\Rightarrow~~ \big|f_n(x) - f_m(x)\big| < \varepsilon, ~~~~~~\forall x \in [-k,k].$$

My idea :
$$\sup\limits_{x \in [-k,k]}\big|f_n(x) - f_m(x)\big| = \sup\limits_{x \in [-k,k]}\left|\cos\left(\frac{x}{2n}\right)\text{sinc}\left(\frac{x}{2n}\right) - \cos\left(\frac{x}{2m}\right)\text{sinc}\left(\frac{x}{2m}\right)\right| \\= \sup\limits_{x \in [-k,k]}\left|\cos\left(\frac{x}{2n}\right)\frac{\sin\left(\frac{x}{2n}\right)}{\frac{x}{2n}} - \cos\left(\frac{x}{2m}\right)\frac{\sin\left(\frac{x}{2m}\right)}{\frac{x}{2m}}\right| \\= \sup\limits_{x \in [-k,k]}\left|\frac{2\sin\left(\frac{x}{2n}\right)\cos\left(\frac{x}{2n}\right)}{\frac{x}{n}} - \frac{2\sin\left(\frac{x}{2m}\right)\cos\left(\frac{x}{2m}\right)}{\frac{x}{m}}\right|\\= \sup\limits_{x \in [-k,k]}\left| \frac{\sin\left(\frac{x}{n}\right)}{\frac{x}{n}}- \frac{\sin\left(\frac{x}{m}\right)}{\frac{x}{m}}\right|.$$
But then I don't know what to do...

Comment: Are you trying to prove, or check, whether for some *fixed* $\;x\in[-k,k]\;$, the sequence $\;\{f_n(x)\}\;$ is a Cauchy sequence?

Comment: @DonAntonio I'd assume so given the calculation so far.

Comment: Hint: Have you considered the reverse triangle inequality in the last step?

Comment: Note that $$\cos \frac{k}{2n}\operatorname{sinc} \frac{k}{2n} \leqslant f_n(x) \leqslant 1$$ for $x\in [-k,k]$ when $n \geqslant k/\pi$.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I'm trying to check whether $\{f_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is a Cauchy sequence.  The $x \in [-k,k]$ should not be fixed.

Comment: With the edit, we see he is asking for uniformly Cauchy.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming my question in the comments above has a positive answer:

$$\begin{align*}&x\neq m\pi\;,\;\;m\in\Bbb Z\implies f_n(x)=\cos\frac x{2n}\cdot\frac{\sin\frac x{2n}}{\frac x{2n}}\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}1\cdot1=1\\{}\\
&x= m\pi\;,\;\;0\neq m\in\Bbb Z\implies f_n(x)=\cos\frac x{2n}\cdot\frac{\sin\frac x{2n}}{\frac x{2n}}\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}1\cdot0=0\\{}\\&x=0\;\implies \text{ The function's undefined on this point}\end{align*}$$

So where the function $\;f_n(x)\;$ ,  for a fixed $\;x\;$ , are defined, they form a converging sequence and thus they are a Cauchy sequence.

Comment: This shows that each $(f_n(x))_n$ is Cauchy (in $\mathbb R$). The question asks to show that $(f_n)$ is Cauchy (presumably for the uniform norm). (Yes this was not so clear at the start.)

Comment: I take the blame for that. My question was ill-posed at first.

Answer (score 0):

Both $\cos(x)$ and $\text{sinc}(x)$ are even continuous functions bounded by 1 and mapping 0 to 1. Therefore, given $0 < \varepsilon < 1$,  you can always find $N \in \mathbb{N}$ big enough to ensure that
$$\cos\left( \frac{x}{2N}\right)\text{sinc}^3\left(\frac{x}{2N}\right) ~<~ \frac{\varepsilon}{2}$$
for all $x \in [-k,k]$.

Now, given $m, n \geq N$, you have
$$ \sup\limits_{|x| \leq k}\left| \cos\left( \frac{x}{2N}\right)\text{sinc}^3\left(\frac{x}{2N}\right) - \cos\left( \frac{x}{2N}\right)\text{sinc}^3\left(\frac{x}{2N}\right)\right| ~\leq~ \varepsilon.$$